# How to access view from other view's event (views are in different branches in layout hierarchy)?

Tags: android, sorting, onclick, android-activity

Let's have an example like below:

```
package xliiv.sandbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Double_tablesActivity extends Activity {

    static final String TAG = "MAIN";
    LinearLayout lay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
        this.lay = lay;

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            boolean heading =  (i == 0) ? true: false; 
            add_table(heading, "" + i);
        }

        this.lay.setOrientation(1);
        setContentView(lay);

    }

    public void add_table(boolean heading, String text) {
        TableLayout t = new TableLayout(this);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setText(text);

        if (heading == true) {
            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                    Log.i(TAG, "onclick: " + tv.getText());

                    //TODO: sort 2nd table denpends on which col of first table was clicked
                    //??
                }
            });
        }

        tr.addView(tv);
        t.addView(tr);
        lay.addView(t);

    }
}
```

I'd like to sort 2nd table depends on which col was clicked in the 1st table?
Suppose there is a method table.sort(col)..
I found getRootView(), so i could use it and go down to second table but there must be better way, than manually searching..

**UPDATE**

After midoalageb's answer here is working version of upper code:

```
package xliiv.sandbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Double_tablesActivity extends Activity {

    static final String TAG = "MAIN";
    LinearLayout lay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
        this.lay = lay;

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            boolean heading =  (i == 0) ? true: false; 
            add_table(heading, "" + i);
            flipper.setTag("tag" + i);
        }

        this.lay.setOrientation(1);
        setContentView(lay);

    }

    public void add_table(boolean heading, String text) {
        TableLayout t = new TableLayout(this);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setText(text);

        if (heading == true) {
            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View root = (View) getRootView();
                    View view_by_tag = (View) root.findViewWithTag("tag2");                 
                    Log.i(TAG, "found table: " + flipper);
                }
            });
        }

        tr.addView(tv);
        t.addView(tr);
        lay.addView(t);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details. For e.g., how many rows & columns per table, how do you get the data to fill the tables?

Comment: Data is taken from database, so i'm able to sort table (by query), the part i can't is ..
Run method (with param, which col was clicked) of 2nd table from 1st table event like onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you fill the table from a database, a better implementation is to replace your 2nd table by a `ListView` and use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fill it.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

Each time you press a key in the first table, requery the `Cursor` of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` using the relevant `ORDER BY` SQL query.

**Update:** If you do not want to change your layout, you can use `View.SetTag` to give a unique Tag for your column when you fill it with data, then in the `OnClickListener` of the first Table, use `View.FindViewWithTag` to find the column of the second table and then use your sort method to sort this table.

Comment: i can't chage all layout since i'm so close to finish it my way. Could You tell me please how to call 2nd table's method from the listener defined in 'quesetion post'? Listener is only defined for 1st table.